# How to execute different XSLTs within an XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xml-parsing

Basically I have 3 separate XSLTs that at the moment work for 3 different XMLs. Instead I want to have a single XSLT which can decide on the basis of a particular  in the incoming to execute a particular XSLT and get the resultant well formed XML.

I tried using the following method -

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">    
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="fruits/apples">
                    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
                      <xsl:template match="/">
                      <data>
                        <doc api_type="2" key="20" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:custom="urn:custom.com" ">
                            <custom:DataSet xyt1:type="tdc:somedataset">
                               <custom:some_table>
                                <custom:anothertable>
                                    <xyt1:key>
                                        <xyt1:fruitqty>
                             <xsl:value-of select="fruit/apple"/>
                                         </xyt1:fruitqty>
                                    </xyt1:key>
                                  <end of this xslt>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="vegetables/tomatoes">
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
                      <xsl:template match="/">
                      <data>
                        <doc api_type="3" key="100" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:custom="urn:custom.com" ">
                            <custom:DataSet xyt1:type="tdc:somedataset2">
                               <custom:some_table2>
                                <custom:anothertable2>
                                    <xyt1:fruitqty>
                             <xsl:value-of select="fruit/oranges"/>
                                         </xyt1:fruitqty>
                                  <end of this xslt2>
        </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

and I will get two different XML files like these -

File 1 -

```
 <fruits>
        <apple>2</apple>        
    </fruits>
```

File 2 -

```
<vegetables>
    <tomatoes>2</tomatoes>        
</vegetables>
```

So I want to execute the first xslt when fruits/apples is found and execute the other for vegetables/tomatoes.

To be precise based on the input XML nodes I want to execute a particular XSLT for which I have individual working files but I want all of them to be in one single XSLT.

This method is going inside the correct block but then is not outputting any of the "nodes", it's just outputting the values inside the XML.

For e.g .- 
it just shows "2" for apples and not the nodes like `<xyt1:fruitqty> 2 </xyt1:fruitqty>.`

As a result I can't get the correctly formatted XML. Any ideas how to get this right?

Comment: Please review: [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I want to execute the first xslt when fruits/apples is found and
>   execute the other for vegetables/tomatoes.

I would suggest you use individual templates to match each type of input, for example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <!-- instructions common to all types -->
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/fruits">
    <!-- instructions for transforming fruits -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/vegetables">
    <!-- instructions for transforming vegetables -->
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have modified the question details. Could you please review it? I want the if else to be based on the XML that's received and execute the appropriate XSLT.

Comment: I have edited my answer to match your new example. I do **not** recommend using "if else" for this.